# Promise.all() - Rejection Id 2 - Not receiving data

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, es6-promise

I am seeing unexpected behavior when calling `Promise.all()`. I can't seem to get the desired data. When the promise is called directly the data returns just fine, but calling `Promise.all()` throws following error:

```
2018-04-09T16:31:35.827Z    77ea5111-3c13-11e8-9800-a5b8cf1bf96f    (node:1) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Cannot read property 'streak' of undefined
```

This is the relevant code:

```
function getUserData(UserId) {
  const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
  const params = {
    TableName: "XXXXXXXXXX",
    Key: {
      "UserId": UserId,
    }
  };

  return docClient.get(params).promise();
}

function buildResponse (UserId, weekNumber, yesterday, today, lastLogin) {
    let currentStreak

    getUserData(UserId);

    getUserData(UserId).then((data) => {    
    currentStreak = data.Item.streak;
    console.log("Streak is " + currentStreak); //Successfully returns "Streak is 22"
     });


    Promise.all([getUserData(UserId)]).then((data) => { //Throws error shown below
    var test = data.Item.streak;
    console.log("Promise is " + test);
    });

}
```

Note: I would like to add multiple promises in the future but I am just starting with one for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) returns an array, you need to destructure the response:

```
Promise.all([getUserData(UserId)]).then(([data]) => { 
  var test = data.Item.streak;
  console.log("Promise is " + test);
});
```

or:

```
Promise.all([getUserData(UserId)]).then((response) => { 
  var [data] = response;
  var test = data.Item.streak;
  console.log("Promise is " + test);
});
```

or extract the data by index:

```
Promise.all([getUserData(UserId)]).then((response) => { 
  var data = response[0];
  var test = data.Item.streak;
  console.log("Promise is " + test);
});
```

additionally you should have .catch() blocks to ensure that errors don't bubble up.

Comment: As with synchronous `try/catch`, you shouldn't have any `catch` blocks unless you can actually do something about the errors.  You *want* them to bubble up otherwise.

Comment: This isn't synchronous try/catch, so I don't see how that is relevant.

Comment: I think he's saying, simply catching and only rethrowing the error is pointless.  In that case might as well omit the catch and let it bubble.

Comment: Many of the same best practices for error handling apply, whether synchronous or asynchronous.

Comment: My intention was not to tell them to catch and re-throw an error but prevent it from bubbling up to top level, as it does in the example they shared.

Comment: This example is trivial enough that it would be reasonable to handle errors inside the `buildResponse` function. I'm just weary of portraying bubbling up of errors as something to be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

As @Hunter pointed out, `Promise.all` resolves with an array of all individual promise results. Arrays don't have an `Item` property, so `data.Item` is undefined, thus accessing `data.Item.streak` gives you the error you're seeing.

It doesn't look like you should be using `Promise.all()`, though. You're only actually waiting on one promise, and unnecessarily wrapping it in an array. Try just taking it out, along with the array brackets:

```
getUserData(UserId).then((data) => {
    var test = data.Item.streak;
    console.log("Promise is " + test);
});
```